# Retain colour but change transparency in photoshop

Tags: colors, transparency, opacity, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

How can I retain a specific colour of an object (or layer) but change the transparency?
I have 2 objects which I want to have a specific colour but currently the opacity is 100%. I need to maintain the current colours but with a opacity of 50%.
Obviously if I change the opacity the colours change (dependent on the background). I need to know how to get an original colour at 100% opacity to make my desired colour at 50% opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so couldn't find a specific way to do it with photoshop so I worked out the math based off the RGB values and came up with a formula to do the job.
For each colour channel I used this formula:

Colour value = Desired Colour + (Background Colour - Desired Colour)*(1-1/Desired Opacity)

eg. 30 = 120 + (255-120)*(1-1/0.6)

Obvious only values between 0-255 are applicable and you may need to round values. This also needs to be done 3 times for red, green and blue.